# Saving additional fields on sign-up in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2, firebase-authentication

We're trying to work out why our information is not sending to our DB, except for email. We want to save name, surname, etc. to Firebase, but it is only saving email. What are we doing wrong?

signup.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { SearchPage } from '../search/search';
import { MyBookingsPage } from '../my-bookings/my-bookings';
import { NavController, AlertController, LoadingController, Loading } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Auth, User, UserDetails, IDetailedError } from '@ionic/cloud-angular';

import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { AuthProvider } from '../../providers/auth/auth';
import { EmailValidator } from '../../validators/email';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-signup',
  templateUrl: 'signup.html'
})
export class SignupPage {
  public signupForm:FormGroup;
  public loading:Loading;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public authProvider:AuthProvider, public formBuilder: FormBuilder, public user: User, public alertCtrl: AlertController, public loadingCtrl:LoadingController) {

  this.signupForm = formBuilder.group({
    name: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
    surname: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
    birthday: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
    licenseNum: [''],
    email: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, EmailValidator.isValid])],
    password: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.minLength(6), Validators.required])]

  });

  }
  signupUser(){
    if (!this.signupForm.valid){
      console.log(this.signupForm.value);
    } else {
      this.authProvider.signupUser(this.signupForm.value.name,
        this.signupForm.value.surname,
        this.signupForm.value.birthday,
        this.signupForm.value.licenseNum,
        this.signupForm.value.email,
        this.signupForm.value.password)
      .then(() => {
        this.loading.dismiss().then( () => {
          this.navCtrl.setRoot(MyBookingsPage);
        });
      }, (error) => {
        this.loading.dismiss().then( () => {
          let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
            message: error.message,
            buttons: [
              {
                text: "Ok",
                role: 'cancel'
              }
            ]
          });
          alert.present();
        });
      });
      this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create();
      this.loading.present();
    }
  }

}
```

auth.ts:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthProvider {

  public fireAuth:firebase.auth.Auth;
  public userProfileRef:firebase.database.Reference;

  constructor(public http: Http) {
    this.fireAuth = firebase.auth();
    this.userProfileRef = firebase.database().ref('/userProfile'); //linked to firebase node userProfile
    console.log('Hello AuthProvider Provider');
  }

  signupUser(name: string, surname: string, birthday: any, licenseNum: string, email: string, password: string ): firebase.Promise<any> {
    return this.fireAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then( newUser => {
      this.userProfileRef.child(newUser.uid).set({
        name: name,
        surname: surname,
        birthday: birthday,
        licenseNum: licenseNum,
        email: email,
        password: password
      });
    });
  }
}
```

[This is the Firebase result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BJF6.png)

We think that the problem is in signupUser in auth.ts, but we really don't know, and we can't find anything online that fits with our structure. If possible, we don't want to have to redo our entire project!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you should use .update(); instead of .set()  function

Comment: This solved it! Thank you so much :)

Comment: @Surjeet: Please create an answer so the OP can accept. Well done btw :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.update()` function instead of `.set()` function to store information at firebase database.